# Targeted push notifications not working if one installation device is not found.

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Good Evening Everyone,

Using the following code I get target push notifications just fine:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Classroom", function(request){
    var teacherThatPosted = request.object.get("userIDs");
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.containedIn("objectId", request.object.get("userIDs"));

    Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery, 
        data: {
            alert: "Test",
            sound: "default"
        }
        }, {
         success: function() {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
        },
            error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

The issue I am having is when a device is added to the installation list and the user deletes the app, phone ID in the install list is no longer valid, so no one will receive notifications. Once, I remove that deleted user from the install list manually, everyone receives notifications just fine. Also, once that user from the installation list is removed, all of the push notifications that are sent push through.

So my question, Is there a way to handle this issue? If so, how?